# Cambiar imagen o icono según el clima

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

tengo 5 iconos, Necesito que cada que cambie el clima, se muestre el icono correspondiente, nublado, soleado etc, `{description: "clear sky", icon: "01d", id: 800, main: "Clear"}` necesito que por ejemplo cuando salga este `clear sky que es día soleado` salga un icono de día soleado, en la imagen muestro el `icon 50d`, que es día nublado, como puedo hacer la función?, que si el estado del clima cambia de `icon` también cambie de imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>pieza clima</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

       
        <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
                <source src="Videos/viento2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      <div id="contenido">
      <div id="content-text"></div>
      <div id="content-text2"></div>
      <div id="content-text3"></div>
<script>

    var _from = document.location.pathname.split('/'); // Permite obtener la ruta del archivo actual y convertirla en array separados por "/"
    _from = _from[_from.length - 1].replace('.html', '').replace('index_', ''); // filtramos el contenido del array y extraemos el nombre del archivo


     $.ajax({url: "http://digital12.xegmenta.com:3000/weather/api/"+_from,
    success: function(result){
      $("#content-text").html(result.name);
      $("#content-text2").html(result.main.temp);
      $("#content-text3").html(result.weather[0].icon);
var ruta_diaSoleado = "iconos/Nublado.png";
var ruta_diaLluvia ="iconos/Soleado.png";
var ruta_diaNublado = "http://www.clubcientificobezmiliana.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/IMG_13400.jpg";
var temperatura = 10;
var temperatura2 = 20;
imagen = document.getElementById('imagen_temperatura');
if(temperatura>9 && temperatura<21){
 imagen.setAttribute('src',ruta_diaSoleado);
}
var delayInMilliseconds = 2000; //retraso de 2 segundos
setTimeout(function() {
  if(temperatura>20 && temperatura<27){
  imagen.setAttribute('src',ruta_diaLluvia);
  }
}, delayInMilliseconds);
      


  }});
    
  </script>
  <h1 class="temperatura">ºC</h1>

  <img src="iconos/Nublado.png" class="img"/>
  <h1 class="dia"><script>
      var meses = new Array ("enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre");
      var diasSemana = new Array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
      var f=new Date();
      document.write(diasSemana[f.getDay()] + ", " + f.getDate() + " de " + meses[f.getMonth()]);
      </script></h1>

<h1 class="hora"><span id="liveclock" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;"></span><script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function show5(){
 if (!document.layers&&!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
 return
  var Digital=new Date()
  var hours=Digital.getHours()
  var minutes=Digital.getMinutes()
  var seconds=Digital.getSeconds()
  var dn="PM"
 if (hours<12)
 dn="AM"
 if (hours>12)
 hours=hours-12
 if (hours==0)
 hours=12
 if (minutes<=9)
  minutes="0"+minutes
  if (seconds<=9)
  seconds="0"+seconds
 //change font size here to your desire
 myclock="<font size='10' face='Arial' ><b><font size='10'></font></br>"+hours+":"+minutes+":"
  +seconds+" "+dn+"</b></font>"
 if (document.layers){
 document.layers.liveclock.document.write(myclock)
 document.layers.liveclock.document.close()
 }
 else if (document.all)
 liveclock.innerHTML=myclock
 else if (document.getElementById)
 document.getElementById("liveclock").innerHTML=myclock
 setTimeout("show5()",1000)
  }
 window.onload=show5
  </script>
</h1>

<script>
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
//se ejecutara despues de 2 segundos
setTimeout(mostrarTexto, 2000);
//se ejecutara despues de 9 segundos
setTimeout(OcultarTexto, 9000);
function mostrarTexto(){
  div = document.getElementById('contenido');
  div.setAttribute("class","overlay");
}
function OcultarTexto(){
div = document.getElementById('contenido');
div.setAttribute("class","ocultar");
}//end function OcultarTexto
</script>
    
        
</body>

</html>
```

tengo lo siguiente en consola:

```js
{base: "stations", clouds: {…}, cod: 200, coord: {…}, dt: 1550775600, …}
1. base: "stations"
2. clouds: {all: 0}
3. cod: 200
4. coord: {lat: 10.96, lon: -74.8}
5. dt: 1550775600
6. id: 3689147
7. main:
1. humidity: 52
2. pressure: 1008
3. temp: 34.39
4. temp_max: 36
5. temp_min: 32
6. __proto__: Object
8. name: "Barranquilla"
9. sys: {country: "CO", id: 8584, message: 0.0038, sunrise: 1550747840, sunset: 1550790493, …}
10. visibility: 10000
11. weather: Array(1)
1. 0: {description: "clear sky", icon: "01d", id: 800, main: "Clear"}
2. length: 1
3. __proto__: Array(0)
12. wind: {deg: 10, speed: 6.2}
13. __proto__: Object
```